# How to create a DLL and use it with Eclipse for C

Tags: c, eclipse, dll

I created a DLL in eclipse like so:
created a C-Project -> shared library (MinGW) -> Name: testdll 
created a header- and a source-file with an simple TestFunction
The source-file is like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

void write(){
    printf("hallo von der dll\n");
}
```

Then I build it and under Debug a libtestdll.dll was created.
That looked good for me so far.

Now I created a C-Hello World-Project called usedll.
The file looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "test.h"

int main(void) {
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    write();
    printf("done\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I created a lib-Folder under project usedll. I copied the libtestdll.dll and the test.h into this folder.

With a right-click on project usedll -> Properties -> C++Build -> Settings -> GCC C Compiler -> Includes -> add (added the lib-Folder from same project usedll)

Then under MinGW C Linker -> Libraries -> Libraries - I added the string libdll

and under Library Search Path I added the lib-folder from the usedll-Project.

The project was now build without errors, but when I executed it, the write-function does not produced any output.

Does someone see what I do wrong ?

Comment: You might want to use a different, more unique name than `write()` for testing.

Comment: Just out of interest - did you mean libtestdll when added to MinGW libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this ...

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampledll

I'll add a snippet below, but I feel you might not have exported your function, reading the above will explain how to do this (using MinGW).

( This snippet has been taken directly from the above webpage )

```
#ifdef BUILDING_EXAMPLE_DLL
#define EXAMPLE_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXAMPLE_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

void __stdcall EXAMPLE_DLL hello(const char *s);
```

Please take note of the use of **__declspec(dllexport)**  and **__declspec(dllimport)**